# Getting TypeError: string indices must be integers. Not Sure Why

Tags: python

Trying to run code where I create empty list by iterating events from json and append userid of any user who did homepage event into the empty list.  I'm trying to use conditional parsing to only parse out 'name' key value with pair 'Visited home page' from the events.json

My code is as follows:

```
import json

#step 1 -- read events file into string
with open('events.json') as events_data:        
#step 2 -- convert string to json object (json.load(string)
 events_data = json.load(events_data)
#print (events_data['events'][0]['name'])
#print(events_data.keys())

#with open ("data/events.json") as events_file:

#step 3 -- create empty list; iterate events list and append userid of any user who did homepage event into the empty list
#that gives us set of user ids who did homepage event
homeuserid = []
for i in events_data['events']:
    homeuserid[i] = i ['name'] ['Visited home page']
print(homeuserid)
```

However when I go the run the code I get the following error and I am unsure why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 34, in <module>
    homeuserid[i] = i ['name'] ['Visited home page']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Sample of JSON (events.json):

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "Added item to cart",
            "timestamp": 1422119921,
            "user_id": "5a5598f2-f7db-420e-9b8e-52a9ad694bc1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Visited product page",
            "timestamp": 1409554014,
            "user_id": "4683c9b6-3c8b-4215-a401-a9bbfde833ee"
        },
        {
            "name": "Visited about page",
            "timestamp": 1430938313,
            "user_id": "26a1593b-b17d-4389-aa93-4a1c9c0e9c67"
        },
        {
            "name": "Added item to cart",
            "timestamp": 1427447392,
            "user_id": "e71f2ee8-09ce-412b-92e1-3c6c0a90dda8"
        },
```

Comment: `event['name']` is a string which can only be indexed by an integer.

Comment: Also, `i` is an entry from your events, and `homeuserid` is a list. `homeuserid[i]` does not make sense.

Comment: The comments in your code make it harder to read than it would be if you left them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the proper way to do it, there's no reason to process the file twice. Note that the resulting list may be empty if there are no `'Visited home page'` events.

```
import json

filepath = 'events.json'

with open(filepath) as events_file:
    events_data = json.load(events_file)

    homeuserids = []
    for event in events_data['events']:
        if event['name'] == 'Visited home page':
            homeuserids.append(event['user_id'])

print(homeuserids)
```